# jQuery Stop fadeOut/fadeIn Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein, fadeout

**Hi Everyone,**

I'm working on a little jQuery, and trying my hand at fading out & in a single element.

What I am trying to achieve from this is to fade a HTML button element out when it is clicked, replacing the text inside, and then fading the button back in with the new text. But when I add the fadeOut(); & fadeIn(); functions to only the first click handler, it creates a fading out/in loop for each time the mouse is clicked. I would only like the first click to fade out & in the button element.

This code is only for experimenting on & as I am only just learning about jQuery, it is not that important if i cant find an answer to this problem. This question is only out of curiosity as to if you can somehow stop the effects from looping.

***HTML Code:***

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>jQuery Test</title>
<meta name="description" content="jQuery Test">
<meta name="author" content="Shannon">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button">Click Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

***jQuery Code: (Before Fading Effect Is Added)***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("button").text("You clicked me!");
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("button").text("You clicked me again!!");
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("button").text("You clicked me 3 times!!!");
    });
    });
    });
});
```

***jQuery Code: (After Fading Effect Is Added)***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("button").fadeOut();
        $("button").text("You clicked me!");
        $("button").fadeIn();
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("button").text("You clicked me again!!");
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("button").text("You clicked me 3 times!!!");
    });
    });
    });
});
```

**Thanks for taking time to read my question, and forgive me if i break any rules on asking questions as this is my first time**

--

Edit:

Thank you all for replying to my question so fast. You all deserve praise on your efforts and knowledge on jQuery. As you can tell, I am still quite a Novice with a long way to go...

--

Comment: Are you saying the first code example somehow works as intended ?

Comment: You are binding multiple click events... in both the cases adding 1 click during each click.. http://jsfiddle.net/BM7qg/. Use `on` and `off` or change your logic.

Comment: Thank you PSL! Your code snippet works great :)

Comment: @ShannonHorcicka if you really want text to change after fadeOut is complete and then fadeIn to happen, use the call back like this http://jsfiddle.net/evEus/. Here is right way, dont repeat button inside the handler,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use on and off to attach/detach the clicks:

### http://jsfiddle.net/82H9A/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").on('click',function () {
        $("button").off('click');
        $("button").fadeOut(function () {
            $("button").text("You clicked me!");
            $("button").fadeIn();
        });
        $("button").on('click', function () {
            $("button").off('click');
            $("button").text("You clicked me again!!");
            $("button").click(function () {
                $("button").text("You clicked me 3 times!!!");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I also set the text and fade in after the fadeout completes...

As it was a poor use of selectors, almost exactly like PSLs first example, I will publish a cleaner version:

### http://jsfiddle.net/82H9A/3/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").on('click',function () {
        var $button = $(this);
        $button.off('click');
        $button.fadeOut(function () {
            $button.text("You clicked me!");
            $button.fadeIn();
        });
        $button.on('click', function () {
            $button.off('click');
            $button.text("You clicked me again!!");
            $button.click(function () {
                $button.text("You clicked me 3 times!!!");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

### Disclaimer:

*While this code is almost identical to what PSL came up with at the same time, but now chooses to complain about, I agree this is a really bad example of how to use selectors. The repeated use of $("button") is for demo purposes only and should not by attempted by anyone except a trained stunt-coder :)*

Comment: This solution is not proper because selector is ambiguous and too generic.. Check the issue here, http://jsfiddle.net/BDfj7/ click on one button and then click on the other. It should ideally be like http://jsfiddle.net/evEus/

Comment: @PSL: The answer was specific to the question code, not an example of how to do it right - I will add a disclaimer. I see now that your own first version (in your question comment) is almost identical so not sure why you choose to complain quite so loudly about this one :)

Comment: Haha, Trained Stunt Coder - Nice touch :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie there is always a room for improvement, and see the second sample in my comment as well. And fyi this is how SO works. And also your first answer you posted before editing was incorrect as well.. it wont show in your edit history since you updated during grace period./

Comment: @PSL: Update added while you were ranting :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie now you posted exactly same as the one i gave you through comments and you dont mention that in your answer.. Well well well !!!

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie i can look at other way as well. Guess what.. :)

Comment: @PSL: If you really think I was able to create that Fiddle in the 57 seconds between your comment and my answer... and fix the fade error you overlooked at the same time... What can I say, you must think I am an amazingingly fast coder. Thanks heaps for the compliment :) *It would take longer than that to copy it even if I had seen your comment in the first place.*

Comment: @PSL: As a test I just copied your "answer" to a new JSFiddle and made my changes... took 91 seconds *even knowing what to fix*... at which time I also noticed *our code was not identical anyway*. Please delete your silly accusations (or at least find sweeter grapes) :)

Comment: Oh God, are those event handlers inside event handlers ?

Comment: @adeneo: Yes, but perfectly valid with `on` and `off`

Comment: @PSL: Thanks for the downvote... 28414 before downvote... now 28413... Not quite as anonymous as you might have hoped. Many thanks.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie oh no. it is for the poor quality of the answer especially for a person of your reputation, not just that answer explains why OPs code behaves that way, it has some poor quality statements in it which does not help in explaining the answer in any way. Also (you might have already known for sure) i had posted the same comment (2nd) in the question way before i commented on your answer with the same fiddle, that might be coincidence (but you yourself guessed it for copying). I can take back my vote if you place proper explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a callback function from the first fadeOut or the text will change whilst the fadeOut is happening.

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('button').fadeOut(function(){
        $(this).text('You Clicked me!').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/6kSxg/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").on('click', function(){
        var self  = $(this),
            speed = 500,
            numb  = self.data('numb')?self.data('numb'):0,
            txt   = {
                1:'You clicked me!',
                2:'You clicked me again!!',
                3:'You clicked me 3 times!!!'
            };
        (function(f) {
            $.when( self.stop(true,true).fadeOut(speed) ).always(function() {
                self.text(txt[f]).fadeIn(speed);
            });
        })(++numb);
        self.data('numb', numb = numb > 2 ? 0 : numb);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/GeEvh/)

Comment: Self executing function... Constants for speed... Use of data for variable storage... Anonymous object creation for string storage... Conditional operators... JQuery Promises... Chaining... **A** for effort, but I think the aim was to clarify something very simple for a newbie, not bury him with cool Javascript/JQuery features. Even I have trouble reading this one :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - Thank you, yes I know, it's great!

Comment: Well putting both the language & library together does seem a little bit to much for me to handle, but it does look quite smart :)

Comment: @adeneo: Er, no. Readability is generally of greater importance. Funny enough though, PSL feels my own really really simple answer requires a detailed explanation and deserved a down-vote (good thing he has not looked at yours!).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - The readabilty of this is great, it's not hard to read at all, the variables are all appropriately named, the jQuery functions speaks for themselves, and the promise is simply because using stop() will cause the built in callback in fadeOut not to trigger. In my opinion this is the way to do it, as event handlers inside event handlers makes me feel dizzy.

Comment: I guess we shall agree to disagree. Attaching a new event handler in side an event is basic stuff. Sorry you get dizzy :)